# Syncing Google Chrome tabs on the fly

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I am wondering if there is a way to sync tabs in Google Chrome in a way that once you open or close a tab on one browser, it opens or closes on all of your other machines. The current sync options is good, but if you start reading on one device and switch to another, you would want that tab to be already open.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial on the subject [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/96664/how-to-sync-open-tabs-across-computers-using-google-chrome/).

Follow he steps.

1. Open up chrome and type `chrome://flags/` into the **omnibar**.
2. Scroll down and look for a flag called **`Enable syncing open tabs`** and enable it.
   [image]
3. Now close chrome and re-launch it. If you click on the wrench menu and select options, switching to Personal Options and selecting Customise under Sync Settings you will see that Open Tabs now appear and are in fact being synced.
   [image]

Note: *Remember that you will have to do this on all the computers that you wish to sync open tabs across. You will also have to be syncing with the same Gmail ID on all the machines.*

Also look at [`this`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en) document on Google Support.

Comment: Thanks @tiago but I dont have this option in my flags page...:(

Comment: This looks like an old tutorial from when the now-standard sync feature was still new and required a flag to enable. "Open Tabs" is now always available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [the Real-Time Tab Sync](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/real-time-tab-sync/bflolmfdngaflefhmapdbbjmclioljck?hl=en) extension should do what you need:

> The extension watches for tab changes and synchronizes them in real time across all of your computers that have it enabled (Chrome on Android does not support extensions yet). Btw you need to enable synchronization in the Chrome settings.